# Effect of linear transformation on the pdf

Tags: probability, statistics, linear-transformations, cumulative-distribution-functions

I was hoping someone could explain the third line of the picture below. Why is it accurate to take the derivative of $F_X$ with respect to $x$ rather than with respect to $y$? I understand the chain rule but do not understand why the derivative of the second term is taken with respect to $x$. Am I missing something very basic?

[image: Linear transformation on the pdf]

Comment: Going from the third-to-last line to the last line is just the chain rule; the second-to-last line is showing an intermediate step of performing the chain rule.

Comment: How do we go from second to third line? Chain rule would suggest taking the derivative of the outer function, which is the Fx(y-b/a), wrt y and then multiplying by the derivative of the inner function (y-b)/a wrt y. Where did the derivative wrt x come from?

Comment: It's just someone else's notation for the process. If you can get from the second line to the fourth line already, the exact symbols they wrote in the third line aren't important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are essentially asking about the chain rule.

**Example.** Consider $X \sim \mathsf{Unif}(0,1),$ so that $f_X(x) = 1,$ for
$0 < x < 1$ is the density function of $X.$ In particular,
$P(0 < X < .1) = 0.1.$

Now, let $Y = g(X) = 3X + 10,$ so that $Y \sim \mathsf{Unif}(10, 13),$ so that $f_Y(y) = 1/3,$ for $10 < y < 13.$ Then
$$P(10 < Y < 10.3) = P(0 < X < .1) = 0.1.$$

In terms of $X,$ this probability is represented by a rectangle
with base $0.1$ and height $1.$ In terms of $Y,$ this probability
is represented by a rectangle with base $0.3$ and height $1/3.$

**Derivation for example.** Now for the calculus: Notice that $g^{-1}(x) = \left(\frac{y-10}{3}\right).$ So, for my specific example, an expanded version of the part you're asking about amounts to:

$$f_Y(y) = \frac{d}{dy}F_X(g^{-1}(x))
= \frac{d}{dy}(g^{-1}(x)) \times \frac{d}{dx}F_X(g^{-1}(x))\\
= \frac{d}{dy}\left(\frac{y-10}{3}\right) \times f_X\left(\frac{y-10}{3}\right)\\
= \frac{1}{3} \times 1 = \frac{1}{3},$$

where the second equality uses the chain rule, the third recognizes that the derivative of the CDF is the density function, and
the last uses $f_X(x) = 1,$ for $0 < x < 1.$

**Simulation of example.** A simulation illustrates the transformation:

```
set.seed(2020)                 # for reproducibility
m = 10^6;  x = runif(m, 0, 1)  # sample 10^6 x-values
y = 3*x + 10                   # transform
par(mfrow=c(1,2))              # enable 2 panels per plot
  hist(x, prob=T, br = seq(0,1,by=.1), col="skyblue2", 
       main="UNIF(0,1)")
    abline(v=c(0,.1), col="red", lwd=2)
  hist(y, prob=T, br = seq(10,13,.3), col="skyblue2", 
       main="UNIF(10,13)")
    abline(v=c(10,10.3), col="red", lwd=2)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))              # return to single-panel plots
```

[image]